# How do I ensure my Apple bluetooth keyboard connects on boot?

Tags: 10.04, keyboard, bluetooth, apple

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 on a laptop and have an Apple bluetooth keyboard which pairs fine.

Every time I turn my computer off and back on again my keyboard stops working. I have to use the keyboard on my laptop to log in.

Once I've logged in, in order to get the wireless keyboard to work, I need disconnect and reconnect it by:

1. Clicking on the Bluetooth icon, select Apple Wireless Keyboard from the drop down menu, then click on Disconnect.
2. Clicking on the Bluetooth icon, select Apple Wireless Keyboard from the drop down menu, then click on Connect.

Looking through syslog, to see what's happening during boot, I find:

```
Nov 25 10:29:21 sony kernel: [   24.525372] apple 0005:05AC:0239.0002: parse failed
Nov 25 10:29:21 sony kernel: [   24.525379] apple: probe of 0005:05AC:0239.0002 failed with error -14
```

and then later in syslog, once I've disconnected then connected the keyboard, I find:

```
Nov 25 10:30:14 sony bluetoothd[1247]: link_key_request (sba=00:21:4F:49:8A:DB, dba=E8:06:88:5A:E0:D4)
Nov 25 10:30:14 sony kernel: [   79.427277] input: Apple Wireless Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb8/8-1/8-1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:12/input11
Nov 25 10:30:14 sony kernel: [   79.427611] apple 0005:05AC:0239.0003: input,hidraw1: BLUETOOTH HID v0.50 Keyboard [Apple Wireless Keyboard] on 00:21:4F:49:8A:DB
```

I can't find anything helpful when Googling "apple: probe of failed with error -14".